# How to make a FPS-like camera in BGE

Tags: game-engine, camera

I would like to make a camera like in most First Person Shooters - similar to GTA. This would mean that the view angle depends on the position of the mouse and the character walks forward, along the view vector.

How can this be achieved in BGE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**. [As of 2.72, there is a new *mouse* actuator](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.72/Game_Development#New_Mouse_Actuator) which you can use to rotate objects based on mouse movement.

Try adding these logic bricks to your camera object:

[image]