# Sensors and actuators to mimic 3D view behavior?

Tags: game-engine

I'd like to make an application using the game engine which has similar interaction to Blender's normal 3D view. Is there a ready-made set of sensors and actuators available to do this? I could do it manually, just don't want to re-invent the wheel here.

Comment: Well,if you don't want to reinvent the wheel, you could use Blender itself :P

Comment: I'm not sure it's even possible to *completely* emulate the 3D view with pure logic bricks atm, but this might get you started: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17964/599,  http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12154/599, and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17967/599

Comment: someonewithpc, you are reminding me of a comment I read the other day [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9083721): "My buddy and I call that 'I asked how to use a ladder, you told me to take the elevator' syndrome. I'm picking apples!" In my case I am using the game engine for display of quad-buffer stereo 3D because it works even though normal blender quad-buffer doesn't work on my GTX card.

Comment: if Orbiting camera is not enough, you would have to use some Python. This BGE app I wrote has many of the interactions of Blender: https://github.com/MolecularFlipbook/FlipbookApp  You can see a video of it here: https://www.molecularflipbook.org/